# How to get Disqus comment count for a page using Disqus PHP API?

Tags: php, api, disqus

How can we get Disqus comment count for a specific page using Disqus PHP?

```
require_once('disqusapi/disqusapi.php');
$disqus = new DisqusAPI('sec_key');
```

Above snippet can be used to initialize the API object. What method to be called if a I have URL of a page in my website?

All my search leads to JavaScript samples to get comment count.

Thanks.

Comment: From the [git page](https://github.com/disqus/disqus-php) it seems you just chain the api calls?! Eg: `forums/listPosts.json` becomes `$disqus->forums->listPosts()`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Just access any of the methods provided by the API:

```
require_once('disqusapi/disqusapi.php');
$disqus = new DisqusAPI('sec_key');
$page_with_comments = $disqus->posts->details(array('thread'=>THREAD_IDENTIFIER));
$comment_count = $page_with_comments->posts;
```

Or get a list of most popular posts:

```
$popular_pages = $disqus->threads->listPopular(array('forum'=>YOUR_SHORTNAME));
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not clear about your question.

You can get the thread details using following API 
https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/details.json.

`response->posts` is comment count for that page.

Comment: Link only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/186281) as they tend to break. Pull relevant portions of your link into this answer so that the information remains available, even if the link does not. Additionally, your link returns `"response":"Invalid API key"`