# Get disqus comment count using PHP

Tags: php, api, disqus

This seems to be an ongoing problem for others aswell as me.. But even following the links under "Questions that may already have your answer" when posting this I still can't get this to work.

All I really want is the comment count for a given article by passing the identifier (Or URL) of the post.

I have downloaded this from github: https://github.com/disqus/disqus-php

And followed the first answer here: [How to get Disqus comment count for a page using Disqus PHP API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630150/how-to-get-disqus-comment-count-for-a-page-using-disqus-php-api) which seemed the closest to what I was trying to achieve. This got me this far:

```
<?php
    require_once('scripts/disqusapi/disqusapi.php');
    $disqus = new DisqusAPI('secret_key');
    $page_with_comments = $disqus->posts->details(array('thread'=>"LINK-IDENTIFIER"));
    $comment_count = $page_with_comments->posts;
?>
```

When I do this however I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Missing required argument: post' in /home/mugheads/public_html/scripts/disqusapi/disqusapi.php:82 Stack trace: #0 /home/mugheads/public_html/test.php(4): DisqusResource->__call('details', Array) #1 /home/mugheads/public_html/test.php(4): DisqusResource->details(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /home/mugheads/public_html/scripts/disqusapi/disqusapi.php on line 82
```

This error indicates that you can no longer use "thread" to retrieve the JSON needed.. and I can't find anyway of finding out what ID Disqus uses for the posts as using "post" like the error describes only accepts an integer.

If anyone knows of a more simple way, or a way which definitely works please share!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: perhaps replaced `thread` with `post`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I do that it tells me post must be an integer.. but there's no way to my knowledge of using id's instead of text to identify posts.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but Google turns up plenty of these SO questions, mostly without any solid answers or answers which rely on this Github API which doesn't seem to work very well.

---

I had been struggling to get the comment count for days, and also tried that API class which seemed to crash my application (probably due to that same fatal error).

After a bit more searching, I came across a link to the JSON output of the Disqus API, and after some playing around, I wrote a quick function to get the comment count:

```
function getDisqusCount($shortname, $articleUrl) {
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listThreads.json?forum=".$shortname."&api_key=".$YourPublicAPIKey),true);

        $array = $json['response'];
        $key = array_search($articleUrl, array_column($array, 'link'));
        return $array[$key]['posts'];
    }
```

You'll need to register an application to get your public API key, which you can do here: https://disqus.com/api/applications/

**What this function does:**

The `$json` array returns much information about the page your comment plugin is on. For example:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
  [feed] => https://SHORTNAME.disqus.com/some_article_url/latest.rss
    [identifiers] => Array
    (
      [0] => CUSTOMIDENTIFIERS
    )

[dislikes] => 0
[likes] => 0
[message] => 
[id] => 5571232032
[createdAt] => 2017-02-21T11:14:33
[category] => 3080471
[author] => 76734285
[userScore] => 0
[isSpam] => 
[signedLink] => https://disq.us/?url=URLENCODEDLINK&key=VWVWeslTZs1K5Gq_BDgctg
[isDeleted] => 
[raw_message] => 
[isClosed] => 
[link] => YOURSITEURLWHERECOMMENTSARE
[slug] => YOURSITESLUG
[forum] => SHORTNAME
[clean_title] => PAGETITLE
[posts] => 0
[userSubscription] => 
[title] => BROWSERTITLE
[highlightedPost] => 
)

 [1] => Array
 (
   ... MORE ARRAYS OF DATA FROM YOUR SHORTNAME FORUM ... etc
 )
)
```

Because the array returns without any useful top level array keys, we do an `array_search` on the array by a column name key which we will know: your page URL where the comments plugin is (`[link]`)

This will then return the top level array key, in this case `0` which we can then pass back to extract the information we want from the array, such as the total comments (array key `posts`).

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is useful. Thanks! Your json as it is will only return 25 threads. It can be increased up to 100 (setting the parameter "limit"). Or even better you can specify the urls setting: "thread:link" (it can even be an array of urls up to 100).
I'm trying to adapt this to retrieve all counters of thousands of posts and save them in mysql. Because disqus count.js is really slow and kills the page speed score.

Comment: @MichaelRogers yeah I built a function to cache all the results because these APIs are kinda sluggish to scrape for the sake of minor data